# Twenty Twelve theme: remove margins

Tags: css, theme-twenty-twelve

Maybe this is too simple question, but I've tried to find out the info by myself.

How can I **remove margins** (all: left, top, right, bottom) for Twenty Twelve theme?

This is what I mean:
[image: WordPress screenshot]

Comment: This is a pure CSS question and as such is off-topic per the [faq]

Comment: @s_ha_dum, oh, sorry. What should I do with this question? (I thought it should be posted here because it requires knowledge of Twenty Twelve theme.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean these class definitions in style.css:

```
    /* =Media queries
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    ...cut...

        .site {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 960px;
            max-width: 68.571428571rem;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    ...cut...

    }


  /* Minimum width of 960 pixels. */
  @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

    ...cut...

    body .site {
        padding: 0 40px;
        padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
        margin-top: 48px;
        margin-top: 3.428571429rem;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
        margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    }

    ...cut...

}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a style.css for a child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Twenty Twelve Child
Theme URI:      http: //example.com/
Description:    Child theme for the Twenty Twelve theme
Author:         birgire
Template:       twentytwelve
Version:        1.0
*/

@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");

/*-----------------
Custom page layout
-------------------*/

/* remove site margin */
body .site{margin:0;max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I make a child theme to safely apply this CSS?

Comment: yes, I recommend it.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. I've created a child theme: `@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");` and after that pasted those definitions. The margins are still here.

Comment: I added the style.css above for the child theme.

Comment: **Brilliant!** Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. One more (small) question please. How to change width of main content and sidebar in percents (I want to reduce sidebar width)?

Comment: ok great, you should be able to do it via the .site-content and .widget-area classes